# Filter column to return only one instance of a name after excluding a string

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to filter a column to return only one instance of each name after excluding a word. When the word 'Agency' is excluded, it returns 2 instances of a name. the first George is where the string 'Agency' was.

```
=(FILTER('Employee List Raw Data'!$B7:$B$100,ISERROR(SEARCH("Agency",'Employee List Raw Data'!$B7:$B$100)))
```

[image]

What i would like is the column to read

Lee

George

Tracey

''''''

```
List Of Names
Bryn Harris
Michelle Dower
Leanne Taylor
Karin Adams
Julie Ashworth
Alice Nicholson
Eloise Parfrey KS
Sandra Fernandes
Eden Constantinof
Lee Tolhurst
Agency STB SG Agency STB SG
George Hilliard
Tracey Heyward
Agency STB Agency STB
Karen Dart
Candice Bell
Sophie Platt
Graham Holland
Tracy Rowe
Sarah Duff
AgencySTB AgencySTB
William Edwards
Sorina Gabriela Rotarciuc
Natasha Tapper
Lorenzo Toribio
Anthony Williams
Tracey Mayall
```

Comment: Seems like you are looking for Unique & Distinct values, could you share the data in Textual format, so that one can copy it --> You can give a try by wrapping your formula within `UNIQUE()` Function

Comment: I have just tried that and still that same problem. Will edit the question with the list of name

Comment: Sir, what is the expected output, sir do you want to exclude the Agency part from the output

Comment: Correct, which my formula does but when it excludes it, it put the name of the person below in its spot

Comment: Sir, just tried this one it worked, could you try once more please `=UNIQUE(FILTER($B$7:$B$100,ISERROR(SEARCH("Agency",$B$7:$B$100))))`

Comment: The above list of names is the source data, but when i used your formula, it just returns Bryn Harris multiple times

Comment: Ah had to be `=UNIQUE(FILTER($B$7:$B$100,ISERROR(SEARCH("Agency",$B$7:$B$100))),TRUE,TRUE)`

Comment: Sir absolutely correct